# Which type of value can be compared in switch statement in Swift2

Tags: swift, object, types, switch-statement, swift2

I wonder which type of value can be compared in switch statement. The official document said:

> Cases can match many different patterns, including interval matches, tuples, and casts to a specific type

Is there anything else? Can I compare class type in switch statement?

Suppose I hava a class A:

```
class A {
}
func == (lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool { return true }
```

Then I can check if two objects of class A are equal. But I still can't do like this:

```
var a1 = A(); var a2 = A()
switch a1 {
case a2: //do something 
}
```

Although we rarely write codes like these, I'm still very curious about how switch statement works in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Expression Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID419),

> The expression represented by the expression pattern is compared with the value of an input expression using the Swift standard library `~=` operator.

You can define `func ~=(lhs: A, rhs: A)` if you wish for your custom type to be used in a `switch` statement.

But I'd also recommend simply using the `Equatable` protocol, implementing `==`, and then you can write `if a1 == a2 { ... }`.

In fact, the standard library provides

```
public func ~=<T : Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool
```

So if you conform to Equatable, you don't need to provide your own `~=`.

Comment: `==` is provided for NSObject subclasses, I believe. It uses `isEqual(_:)`.

Comment: It seems that I can write if a1 == a2 { ... } even if class A doesn't conform to `Equatable` protocol , and overload `==` operator is enough. In conclusion, do you mean any type which overloads their `~=` operator can be compared in switch statement?

Comment: You can ⌘-click on the `==` operator to see where it's defined. Yes, `~=` is what's used for `switch` statements.

Comment: `==` is defined in Swift module. I am still not clear about if I have to conform to `Equatable` explicitly or just overload `==` operator is enough. Also, what do you mean by `isEqual(_:)`, I think it is a method in Objective-C

Comment: If you are already providing `==` then I would recommend conforming to `Equatable` because you'll get access to various extensions such as SequenceType's `split` and `startsWith` etc. I also updated my answer — if you are Equatable, you don't need a custom `~=`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.